# How to fix this problem with tikz knots and decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Using the `knots` package, which is part of Andrew Stacey's [spath3](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3), one can draw beautiful paths that cross each other.
However, there are problems when combining it with decorations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw[knot=black,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, adding the `knot` style to the path makes the decoration white, or invisible or whatever. It doesn't depend on the order in which I specify the styles.

How can I avoid this? Is it a feature or a bug?

Comment: This seems to work for your MWE, but I am not sure if it will be a solution in more complicated situations:         `\draw[knot=black,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},preaction=decorate] (0,0) -- (1,0);`

Comment: Good idea! It "nearly" works, it seems that with that option the arrow is not connected to the path anymore, but there is a small white space between them.

Comment: Ah, yes; you're right. Not the path interrupts the arrow. Forget my previous comment.

Comment: An ugly hack is to first draw the `knot` path and the use a path just for the decoration:         `\draw[knot=black] (0,0) -- (1,0);
        \path[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},decorate] (0,0) -- (1,0);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `knot` style makes the path a "doubled" path, only unlike a usual doubled path then the outside part is set to the background and the inside set to the desired colour.  This is what allows a knot path to "punch through" another path.  As this is not the usual way of using the `double` style, the arrow head is picking up the wrong colour (and thickness) from the path.  You can override the arrow's defaults by using an optional argument to the `\arrow` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193636/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw[knot=black,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[black,thin]{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[white,double=black,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[black,thin]{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,-1) -- (1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The third line shows that the problem is caused by the `double` and not by any other feature of the `knot` package.)

[image: Lines with arrows on them]

Comment: Always a pleasure seing your answers.